# How to map recursive nested objects with ExpressMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, express-mapper

I'm working on a web application (EF6 code first) that enable users to fill out evaluations. An evaluation contains multiple question, a question contains multiple subquestion.
Each subquestion have a "mapping feature" that enable user to associate a subquestion to another existing subquestion.

I have the following Entity Framework models (I removed some of the properties since they are not needed for my example)

```
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubQuestion> SubQuestions { get; set; }
}
public class SubQuestion
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    //These 2 properties are used to create a many-to-many table for the mapping of subquestions
    //Automatic name = SubQuestion_ID
    //Subquestion of current evaluation to map to another evaluation
    public virtual ICollection<SubQuestion> SubquestionCurrentMapping { get; set; }

    //Automatic name = SubQuestion_ID1
    //Subquestion of evaluation the current evaluation is mapped to
    public virtual ICollection<SubQuestion> SubquestionPreviousMapping { get; set; }

}
```

In the project we are using the following DTO objects

```
public class QuestionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubQuestionVM> SubQuestions { get; set; } = new List<SubQuestionVM>();
}

public class SubQuestionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerVM> Answers { get; set; }

    public List<SubQuestionVM> SubquestionCurrentMapping { get; set; }
}
```

We are using ExpressMapper (see http://expressmapper.org). We have a method that do the mapping of all DTO with EF models that goes like this:

```
public void MappingRegistration()
{
    Mapper.Register<Question, QuestionVM>();
    Mapper.Register<SubQuestion, SubQuestionVM>();
    Mapper.Compile();
}
```

Everything was mapped and working fine until I added the following property in the subquestionVM:

```
public List<SubQuestionVM> SubquestionCurrentMapping { get; set; }
```

This property create a many-to-many table to link subquestions together for a mapping feature.

When I try to start the application, I get the following error:

> "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."

---

The changes I tried were those:
In SubquestionVM

```
//public List<SubQuestionVM> SubquestionCurrentMapping { get; set; }                                                                         
public List<SubQuestionMappedVM> SubquestionCurrentMapping { get; set; } = new List<SubQuestionMappedVM>(); //Trying to fix by changing vm
```

There is my new VM for testing:

```
public class SubQuestionMappedVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Remove this property, don't need more than 1 level of recursion anyway
    //public List<SubQuestionMappedVM> SubquestionCurrentMapping { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerVM> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I also added the new VM to the method that does the mapping:

```
Mapper.Register<SubQuestion, SubQuestionMappedVM>();
```

I think my problem is because I'm mapping a subquestionVM which contains a list of subquestionVM creating a recursion. I'm trying to create a different subquestionVM to bypass the problem but my web page doesn't even display in my browser. After a lengthy 1min45, Visual Studio respond with "A task was canceled.".

If anyone have any knowledge of how to map my recursive SubquestionVM, how to use a different VM to stop recursion or any other solution that prevent the stack overflow error, I'm appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem:

I couldn't figure out how to use ExpressMapper or different View Model to bypass the stack overflow exception, so I created a method that does a manual mapping from the EF model to the DTO model.

```
/// <summary>
/// Map list of SubquestionVM (SubquestionCurrentMapping) with data from current Component (EF model).
/// 
/// Why are we doing this?
///     Because when using the ExpressMapping to map 'SubQuestion' to 'SubQuestionVM', it creates a stack overflow error on the property 'SubquestionCurrentMapping'
///     which is caused by recursive VM.
///     I originaly tried alternative solution like:
///         changing 'List<SubQuestionVM>' for 'List<SubQuestionMappedVM>' but the website was not even loading (even with proper value in the new VM, and global.asax),
///         loading the faulty property later on, but any attempt to populate the object was resulting in an overflow at a moment or another.
///     Thankfully the manual mapping is proven to be effective and errorless!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="evaluationVM"></param>
/// <param name="component"></param>
private static void ManualMappingOfRecursiveSubquestionVM(CurrentEvaluationVM evaluationVM, Component component)
{
    foreach (var subquestion in component?.Question?.SubQuestions)
    {
        //Find corresponding subquestionVM and manually map them
        var subquestionVM = evaluationVM.CurrentComponent?.Question?.SubQuestions.Find(s => s.ID == subquestion.ID);

        foreach (var subquestionMapping in subquestion.SubquestionCurrentMapping.ToList())
        {
            var tempSubquestionVM = new SubQuestionVM
            {
                ID = subquestionMapping.ID,
                QuestionID = subquestionMapping.QuestionID,
                Name = subquestionMapping.Name,
                Clarification = subquestionMapping.Clarification,
                Description = subquestionMapping.Description,
                Index = subquestionMapping.Index,
                CanSelectGoal = subquestionMapping.CanSelectGoal,
                IsDate = subquestionMapping.IsDate,
                Deprecated = subquestionMapping.Deprecated,
                MultipleChoices = subquestionMapping.MultipleChoices.Map<ICollection<MultipleChoice>, List<MultipleChoiceVM>>(),
                Answers = subquestionMapping.Answers.Map<ICollection<Answer>, List<AnswerVM>>()
            };
            subquestionVM.SubquestionCurrentMapping.Add(tempSubquestionVM);
        }
    }
}
```